# App inventor when canvas touched detect which spriteimage was touched

Tags: app-inventor

Hi in app inventor is there a way to detect which imagesprite was touched. I want to use the header to set a global index.

Thanks in advance

Comment: which header are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry Heading. The imageSprite has a property Heading is this not to add a value?

Comment: heading is the direction, the sprite is moving to, see the [documentation](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/animation.html#ImageSprite) `Heading: Returns the sprite's heading in degrees above the positive x-axis. Zero degrees is toward the right of the screen; 90 degrees is toward the top of the screen.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, each image sprite has its own `Touched` event, for example ImageSprite1:

[image]

In the `Canvas.Touched` event you only can get the information, if an image sprite was touched or not

[image]

http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/animation.html#Canvas

> **Touched(number x, number y, boolean touchedSprite)**
>       When the user touches the canvas and then immediately lifts finger: provides the (x,y) position of the touch, relative to the
>   upper left of the canvas. TouchedSprite is true if the same touch also
>   touched a sprite, and false otherwise.

Comment: I am discussing when Canvas1.Touched. touchedSprite. It can recognise if it has touched a sprite can in not return which sprite it has touched. I understand that touchSprite is returned as a boolean expression.

Comment: OK I will ask a different question. I don't think it is possible what I am trying to do. Basically, Instead of having when ImageSprite1.touched for every image I wanted something like a listener. That would Identify the spriteImage by it's name.

Comment: you will have to use the events, which are available, in this case the different `Touched` events of the image sprites. But you can call a procedure from each event and pass the `image sprite component` as parameter to avoid redundancy.